# Accessing Graph API in Multi-tenanted function app

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-functions

I am trying to build a Function App that connects to the Graph API and reads the available emails. I am able to retrieve emails from one tenant which has the email permissions listed in 'API Permissions' with the name of the specific tenant. However, when I sign in using another tenancy the consent screen where Permission is requested is empty. And if I try to perform a request to pull emails I get a Authorization_RequestDenied "Insufficient privileges to complete the operation." error. Is there something I am missing or am I not able to retrieve emails from another tenancy like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely your `scope` parameter when authenticating does not include the permission you specified.
*Statically defined permissions* (the ones defined in portal) are used if you use the special ".default" scope.
So instead of e.g. "User.Read" as scope, you can use:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/.default
```

Documentation for .default scope: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-permissions-and-consent#the-default-scope

Comment: This fixed it thanks!